# Calling VROUNDSS using Rust intrinsics

Tags: rust, x86-64, sse, avx

From what I see [here](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/roundss):

I can call "roundss" (SSE 4.2) by using the Rust intrinsic: core::arch::x86_64::_mm_round_ss.

but I'm unable to find an equivalent for "vroundss" (AVX?). Is there a way to call this instruction in Rust?

I found no match in Rust documentation for this specific instruction.

Comment: Use the same `core::arch::x86_64::_mm_round_ss` in a build with AVX enabled, and the compiler will use the AVX VEX encoding (`vroundss`) for everything instead of legacy SSE.  (Use the Rust equivalent of `-march=native` or `-march=x86-64-v3` or whatever, or just `-mavx`)

Comment: The corresponding switches for Rust are `-C --target-cpu=native` and `-C --target-feature=+avx` see [godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/ohKfv6sPz)